# sklearn RidgeClassifierCV: unexpected keyword argument 'random_state'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Why does `RidgeClassifierCV` from `sklearn.linear_model` not have a `random_state` keyword argument?

It cross-validates `RidgeClassifier`, which does have `random_state`. Should this keyword not be passed on? Or am I missing something here?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-612-4d3d523acbab> in <module>()
      1 # Apply ridge regression
----> 2 model = linear_model.RidgeClassifierCV(cv=3, normalize=True, random_state=random_state)
      3 model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
      4 model = linear_model.RidgeClassifier(alpha=model.alpha_, normalize=True,
      5                                      random_state=random_state)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'random_state'
```

Comment: there is no need for `random_state ` in the `RidgeClassifierCV `. `RidgeClassifierCV ` will just split the data and fit/predict.

Comment: But doesn't this fit/predict use a random_state that could lead to different results and thus to a different regularization parameter after CV?